# Getting URL Data Using RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, background-process

I am trying to convert my old async task code into RxJava code. The goal of the code is to load JSON data from a url, store it in a ArrayList that is used as an adapter for my arraylist.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    private String url = "https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=10&start-with-lorem=10";
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        try
        {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.isSuccessful();
        }catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("Network request", "Failure", e);
        }

        return false;
    })

            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe((result) -> {
                //results supposed to go here don't know how to connect it
            });
```

Once I've passed in the URL, how do I subscribe those results and put them in the array list?

Thanks :)

Comment: so, what's the problem? Just write something like `savedResult = result` in the penultimate string

Comment: you'll need to change what is returned in the `fromCallable`block as right now the status is returned in the form of a boolean with `isSuccessful`. Get the response data from `response` and return that instead

Comment: could you show an example of that? @WilliamReed